# Using HttpClient to invoke a webservice in an android app

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am new to android & web services.I I want to create an android app which consume a webservice using HttpClient.
Yet i am confused with, how to do this. I'll explain what i've needed to do.

Say,we have a webservice at http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx
WSDL url=http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL

What I need is to call the method "FahrenheitToCelsius" & return values from it in an android app.Can't i do this using HttpClient? Since it seems to get only the HTTP methods like GET and POST.

When I search on  this ,I found  the below site as a more frequent suggestion. But it doesn't contain ,what I need to do.
http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/

(I could call "FahrenheitToCelsius" method & return values using ksoap library.But now i need to do it using HttpClient too)

Answer (score 1):

To clarify-  When you connect to a webservice via its WSDL file, you're consuming a very specific kind of webservice— specifically, a [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) webservice.

The typically way to connect to a SOAP webservice is to either find a library in your language of choice, or find a utility that will use the WSDL to generate code for you that communicates with the webservice.

One popular utility for connecting to SOAP on Android is called [ksoap-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,I've tried it using ksoap.But I need to use the other way too,(using HttpClient).